# Django reading index of each item returned

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm returning a list of items in a standard for loop in the template. Is is possible to get the index value of each item returned.

```
{% for entry in latest_entries %}
    <li class="list-item">
        <button class="button button-circle"><span class="list-index">1</span></button>
        <a class="SidebarLatestTitle" href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    </li>
 {% endfor %}
```

I'd like for the hard-coded '1' in the button to return the correct number in the list. If 10 results are returned then (1-10). Does Django provide a way to access this number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you are asking about [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for):

> `forloop.counter` - The current iteration of the loop (1-indexed)

```
{% for entry in latest_entries %}
    <li class="list-item">
        <button class="button button-circle"><span class="list-index">{{ forloop.counter }}</span></button>
        <a class="SidebarLatestTitle" href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah, you type faster than I do :)

Comment: @Pran you should have beaten me - slept for like 1 hour today and, I think, I'm still drunk :) I've just probably opened the question earlier.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Using the magical `forloop.counter` or `forloop.counter0`